# How To Change Text from HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a node.js project but I can't get something done:

How to change dynamically a text from a html file?

Here in the HTML file I have the following lines:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12 offset-xl-5">
                        <code id=someId'><strong>{%CODE%}</strong></code>
                    </div>
```

and in the controller file in Node.js, I'm calling the replace function:

```
var index = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../view/index.html`, 'utf-8');

index = index.replace(/{%CODE%}/gm, 'someText');
fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/../view/index.html`, index);
```

Now, the file will contain 'someText' instead of {%CODE%}. But, somewhen in the future, I will want to change it too.

Let's say it's like a calculator. I want to show the answer everytime, dynamically, not to hard code it.

In fact, I have an email checker site. I want to display if the email is or not valid, in the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems likely that multiline flag is missing.

```js
data.replace(/{%CODE%}/gm, 'someText');
```

Also, `read/writeFileSync` don't accept callbacks, so the callback in `readFileSync` is simply ignored.

Comment: Oh, it worked now. The problem was I declared index as const, not a var. That was a lame mistake, I'm sorry and thank you for your answer!

Comment: @BogdanDoncea glad if I was able to help :)